# Proper use of offsets/push

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a Bootstrap site and I was wondering if this is acceptable. The site looks how I want it to, but I was wondering if this is best practice?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-1">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The approach I'm taking is to use **1 offset for every two missing columns**, and **use a push for every missing column**. What would be the best way to rewrite this for semantic purposes, if at all necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Bootstrap `offset` is perfectly acceptable! What you are using it for (filling in missing columns) is perfectly acceptable too. They would not add it unless they didn't want you to use it.

If you where to *not* use `offset` then the only way to move stuff around would be `margin` (generally). The problem with that is that it ruins the point of using a grid system!

So IMO I think it is perfectly OK to use Bootstrap `offset`. I use it all the time in my website! :)

Comment: Yea, I use it for when I am to lazy to actually change the CSS, and I would like to center a div. Perhaps sometimes I use code like this `col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3`. It centers the div, and requires no extra CSS.

Comment: @hufflapuff maybe mark as correct if right answer? :)